# How to generate ANTLR recognizer again in Intellij after editing grammar

Tags: java, intellij-idea, antlr

I have written a grammar to rotate a robot.

```
grammar RobotController;

//Parser
program: statement+;
statement: rotateStatements;
rotateStatements: ROTATE EOS;

//lexer
ROTATE: 'rotate';
EOS: ';';
```

Then i created ANTLR recognizer and it worked, It created some Java files with some code.
Later on I modified my grammar
to

```
grammar RobotController;

//Parser
program: statement+;
statement: rotateStatements;
rotateStatements: ROTATE (LPAREN direction RPAREN)? EOS;
direction: STRING;

//lexer
ROTATE: 'rotate';
LPAREN: '(';
RPAREN: ')';
EOS: ';';
STRING:  '"' (~[\r\n])* '"';
```

Now I am creating ANTLR recognizer again but the previously generated Java files remain the same in the system. No new code is added to them.

Does anyone know how to generate ANTLR recognizer after modifying the grammar?

Comment: Did you run the new grammer through Antlr4, which should create java code, and then compile the Java files through the javac compiler?

Comment: Yes i tried, In intellij It is usually done by right click and create ANTLR recognizer. I wrote grammar then build the project and tried creating recognizer, but it is not working

Comment: By the way what do you mean by running grammar through ANTLR, for the first time, i just wrote the grammar and created recognizer, It worked without running it anywhere

Comment: Do you use ANTLR with Maven by any chance? Don't forget to `clean`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

INFO: Restarting Intellij and invalidating cache solved the problem

Comment: If your answer answers your question, please accept your answer. (It is very well accepted on StackOverflow to answer and accept own questions). Oh, and welcome to StackOverflow, even thou you are already here for some time.